# How to style textarea-element in grid column?

Tags: reactjs, css, css-grid, styled-components

I am using react with `styledcomponents` and getting my head around css-grid, having trouble aligning the `textarea`, can't get right height(overflows in next row) and width (has to align with 'col3' on the right side) :

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    display:grid
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 30px;
    grid-template-rows:25% 25% auto;
    justify-items: start;
    border: solid 1px   #000000
    `

const ColumnSpan2 = styled.div`
    grid-column: 2/4;
    grid-row: row 2;
`;
```

The component looks like this:

```
<Wrapper>
            <Column1>
                <select>
                    <option>een</option>
                    <option>twee</option>
                </select>
            </Column1>
            <Column2>
                <input type="text" value="col2" />{' '}
            </Column2>
            <Column3>
                <input type="text" value="col3" />{' '}
            </Column3>
            <Column4>todo iceon </Column4>
            <ColumnSpan2>
                {' '}
                <textarea>Hello comments here</textarea>
            </ColumnSpan2>
</Wrapper>
```

css:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 60%;
}

textarea{
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%
  }
```

How can I get the right style for the `textarea` (I tried changing the `grid-template-rows` prop but not giving a solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a vanilla CSS representation of you react code - here are some pointers:

- [**`justify-items: start`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items) will align the content *inside* a grid items - consider removing it (and `width: 200%` etc too I guess you were trying to solve it keeping `justify-items`)
- now set width of the `input`, `select` and `textarea` to *fill* their grid cells using `width: 100%`
- `grid-row: row 2` is invalid as you don't have a [**`named grid-line`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Layout_using_Named_Grid_Lines) in `grid-template-rows` definition - change it to `grid-row: 2`,
- you don't have defined a height for the *grid container* - so you can change `grid-template-rows` to `grid-template-rows: auto auto`,
- also note the usage of `grid-gap` and `padding` to adjust the *spaces* between the *grid items*.

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 60%;
}

textarea, input, select {
  width: 100%; /* extend the width of the grid item */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* including padding / border in width */
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 30px;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto; /* changed */
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  grid-gap: 10px; /* grid gap to handle spaces between items if needed */
  padding: 5px; /* space between wrapper and grid items */
}

.column1 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

.column2 {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

.column3 {
  grid-column: 3/4;
}

.column4 {
  grid-column: 4/5;
}

.colspan2 {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 2; /* changed */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="column1">
    <select>
      <option>een</option>
      <option>twee</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <input type="text" value="col2" />
  </div>
  <div class="column3">
    <input type="text" value="col3" />
  </div>
  <div class="column4">(i)</div>
  <div class="colspan2">
    <textarea>Hello comments here</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have another small question regarding this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55563585/how-to-align-elements-in-cells-of-a-css-grid